# Ansible ad-hoc bracket expansion

Tags: linux, ansible

Is it possible to use bracket expansion in an ad-hoc command? I'm trying to do:

```
ansible web3 -m shell -a "sudo gzip /var/opt/tomcat/logs/appname.log.2015-05-2{4..7}" -K
```

But it's being interpreted as a string. Is this a situation where I might need to use xargs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is the host `web3` a recent Debian/Ubuntu server where `/bin/sh` is actually [dash](http://gondor.apana.org.au/~herbert/dash/)?  The bracket expansion is not supported by it.  You might need to specify `executable` option to [shell module](http://docs.ansible.com/shell_module.html).

```
$ ansible -i localhost, all -m shell -a 'ls /var/log/syslog.{2..4}.gz'
localhost | FAILED | rc=2 >>
ls: cannot access /var/log/syslog.{2..4}.gz: No such file or directory

$ ansible -i localhost, all -m shell -a 'ls /var/log/syslog.{2..4}.gz executable=/bin/bash'
localhost | success | rc=0 >>
/var/log/syslog.2.gz
/var/log/syslog.3.gz
/var/log/syslog.4.gz
```